# time date format [R]

Tags: r, date, dataframe, format, time-series

I have a `time series` data frame `df`

```
         date       lang     revenue   year month 
1     01/01/2014   DE-DE      8146.5   2014     1        
2     02/01/2014   EN-GB    31416.95   2014     1           
3     03/01/2014   EN-US      152646   2014     1              
4     04/01/2014   ES-ES       15523   2014     1        
5     05/01/2014   FR-FR      4221.5   2014     1        
6     06/01/2014   IT-IT     12971.7   2014     1
```

...

My goal is: create a `**week variable**` which depends on `date` calendar and save it to my `df`.

1. I changed the `date` format to from `factor` to `date`

   `df$date = as.Date(df$date)`

However, the results become like this

```
"0001-01-20" "0002-01-20" "0003-01-20" "0004-01-20" ...
```

I tried to add the `time format`

`df$date = as.Date(df$date, format = "%d-%m-%y")`

but the results are still the same.

What is the problem?

2. Create a week variable which depends on my date calendar

`strftime(df$date,format="%W")`

However, the results don't make any sense:

`"03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "02" "03" "03"
  [20] "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03" "03"
  [39] "03"`

I am wondering where goes wrong? (perhaps the 2nd question will be solved when the 1st question is solved?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to specify the `format`

```
 as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```